# Associating accounts via IP logs

Tags: sql, algorithm

In my application, I need to associate accounts via shared IPs to monitor for abuse/collusion.

I've come up with the following principles:

- Two accounts sharing an IP more than 5 times on each side are **majorly associated**
- Two accounts sharing an IP that were not majorly associated, are **minorly associated**
- The property of being **majorly associated** is transitive (ie. A is associated with C if they are both associated with B).
- An account A is **minorly associated** with all accounts that are minorly associated to any account it is majorly associated with (ie. If C is minorly associated with D and A is majorly associated with C, A is minorly associated with D).

I have a table of account/IP logs set up like so:

```
TABLE ip_logs (
    account_id INT,
    persona_id INT,
    ip TEXT,
    datetime TEXT,
    count INT
)
```

The count and datetime are updated as users log in, if a row already exists for their account/persona/ip. The persona_id is not relevant to this problem.

I also have a simplification:

- It will suffice to relate majorly associated accounts only up to and including 2 hops away from the starting account, I don't need to exhaust the transitive properly.

My question is... What is the best way for me to build this list of associated accounts (majorly and minorly) for any given account_id, by querying the database?

For example, I can get immediately **majorly associated** accounts like so:

```
SELECT account_id FROM ip_logs WHERE account_id AND ip IN (SELECT ip FROM ip_logs WHERE account_id=:account_id GROUP BY ip HAVING SUM(count) > 5) GROUP BY account_id HAVING SUM(count) > 5
```

I could use this call recursively (or up to depth 2) on the results to create a master list of **majorly associated** accounts, and then use a similar query in the end (without the HAVING) to get **minorly associated** accounts.

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

I'm also considering maintaining this data in a separate table as ip_logs is updated, rather than having to derive it from ip_logs every time, which could be substantial overhead.